# weakself inside dispatch_async queue(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{})

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, weak-references, retain-cycle, strong-references

Below code snippet is in **objective C**

```
__weak MyView *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakSelf.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [weakSelf.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];
    weakSelf.activityIndicatorView = nil;
});
```

1. Will the **`weakSelf`** always available/valid since it is inside the main
   queue?
2. Do we need to declare **`strongSelf`** only when block is other
   than the main queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet is too small to answer on your questions fully.

1. `weakSelf` can be both `nil` or non-nil. The keyword `weak` means that variable `weakSelf` can become `nil` in some cases. For example, if your controller has the following property:

   ```
   @property (retain) MyView* myView;
   ```

   In some cases you dismiss this controller and after that you call the method `f` for `myView`:

   ```
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

       [self.myView f];
   }];
   ```

   Code of the method `f` is based on code snipped you provided in this question:

   ```
   -(void)f {

       [self removeFromSuperview];
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           __weak MyView *weakSelf = self;
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

               [weakSelf.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
               [weakSelf.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];
               weakSelf.activityIndicatorView = nil;
           });
       });
   }
   ```

   I guess you will see in debugger that the `weakSelf` will be `nil` when you will try to call `stopAnimating` for `activityIndicatorView`. And I guess you can easily reproduce the situation when `weakSelf` will be not cleared. It means that the answer on your first question is "No, the `weakSelf` will be not always available/valid and the main thread does not protect you from `nil` in this variable"
2. You need to use `strongSelf` (`__strong` instead of `__weak`) if you don't want to loose a reference to variable inside block. For example, if in the class `MyView` there is a method `log` that logs some debug information:

   ```
   -(void)log {

       NSLog(@"LOG");
   }
   ```

   And if you want to log information always after the code in your code snippet will called use the following version of the method `f`:

   ```
   -(void)f {

       [self removeFromSuperview];
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           __strong MyView *weakSelf = self;
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

               [weakSelf.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
               [weakSelf.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];
               weakSelf.activityIndicatorView = nil;
               [weakSelf log];
           });
       });
   }
   ```

   So, the answer, on your second question is "No, you need to use `__strong` based on your application, the block can be completed in different threads".